# XML with inline schema supported in Excel?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I need to generate a simple XML file (a list of users) with an XSD so this XML can be imported in Excel (2010+). The fields presented by this XML are dynamic, it's up to the user which fields he wants/needs. The list can be long and I have about 40 fields the user can select from.

Excel builds his table columns based upon the XML schema. If the first row has missing fields, these would be added to the table in a wrong order. So a schema is required! Since the XML is based on the request, the XML schema **must** be inline.

Based on about every article I could find about inline schema's I've created the following.. but it will crash'n burn every validator. Excel won't accept it either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<users xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="#local">
  <xs:schema id="local" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="users">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:any processContents="skip" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element ref="user" minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='unbounded'/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="user">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="firstname" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
          <xs:element ref="lastname" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
          <xs:element ref="phone" minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string"/>

  </xs:schema>

  <user>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <phone>123456789</phone>
  </user>
  <user>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Something</lastname>
  </user>
  <user>
    <firstname>Jesus</firstname>
    <lastname>Christ</lastname>
    <phone>987654321</phone>
  </user>
</users>
```

What the heck am I doing wrong? It seems so simple...

Comment: Currently as a workaround I am using an external XSD. xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation gets added with a fixed url to our local webserver containing the same request. Instead of generating data, this request only generates an XML schema. I suspect that Excel does not support inline schema's